# Telling the browser to open or download a file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, mime-types, codeigniter-2

In Codeigniter, we can use the `force_download($file_name,$data)` function from the download helper to force the browser to download a file.

But this is not what I need, I would like Codeigniter to respond a http header with the MIME type that the file corresponds to, so that the browser may or may not download the file, depending on whether there is an application registered for that MIME type on the client machine (if there is one, that application will open that file).

Is there a way of doing this with Codeigniter?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot do that with Codeigniter.

Generally speaking, with server-side technologies like PHP, you can only send content to the client, not directly interact with the client.  It is up to the client to do what they wish with whatever piece of content you send them.  Even with client side tools like javascript, (thankfully) you can only have limited interaction with the client machine.  What you are wanting to do is allow a website to (automatically) upon visiting, download a piece of software, and execute it on the client machine...

that's called malware...  (brought to you by the makers of [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX))

***Above was in direct response to***

> "...so that the browser may or may not download the file, depending on whether there is an application registered for that MIME type on the client machine (if there is one, that application will open that file).

**UPDATE**

You can set the mime type through plain php header manipulation.  The following example is taken directly from the php [`header()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) as the first example.

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: Not really malware, users have uploaded some files and I put them in a place outside the webroot. A user can only download the files that he/she has uploaded. So I created a route in Codeigniter and inside the corresponding function in the controller, I serve them the files only if they have logged in (authenticated). I am using file_get_contents to read in the file and now I need a function like force_download that tells the browser to download/open the file as if the file is served from the webroot.

Comment: So I would like to know if CI has provided such a function that sends the file to the client browser (specifying the correct MIME for me in the http response header) and let the browser decides what to do with it. The problem of force_download is, it forces the browser to download the file (which is not what I want) by using a MIME type normally not registered by any application on the client computer.

Comment: I have founded the MIME mapping array in the application/config/mimes.php in Codeigniter, combining with your PHP codes, it should be very easy to write a function that exactly achieve what I need.